# Does git protect you from unauthorized repository modification?

Tags: git

Could the <3-letter government agency> add a back door to a project through their git repository without anyone noticing the changes?

For example, if a malicious hacker got hold of contributor access to [Ruby's git](https://github.com/ruby/ruby) could they mess with the commit history in such a way that pulling malicious code could go unnoticed?

Comment: What does "without anyone noticing the changes" mean? If someone doesn't look at what they're pulling when they pull code from a remote repository, of course it's possible they're downloading malicious code. But you can see the changes in each pull. (And do you mean if the remote owner is adding the malicious code, or if someone is hacking into it to add the code?)

Comment: @DavidRobinson Added an example to my original question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as modifying the change history of the project goes, it will be difficult; git uses what could be viewed as a 'filesystem snapshot' of the changes.  The identifier git uses to differentiate these change snapshots is a 160bit SHA1 hash.

While cryptographically secure, this is not used in git to protect against malicious rewriting of the repository, but for basic data integrity.  If a previous commit is changed, the SHA1 commit identifier will change, but theoretically, a collision could be found.

In git, the cryptographic nature of the SHA1 hash is not a security mechanism *per se*, but a bonus

Your question has come up before in reference to the linux kernel being maliciously changed. You can read it [here](http://joeyh.name/blog/entry/size_of_the_git_sha1_collision_attack_surface/).

Comment: Thank you for the article. My question was sparked by an article regarding the [2003 linux backdoor attempt](https://freedom-to-tinker.com/blog/felten/the-linux-backdoor-attempt-of-2003/). I knew git uses sha identifiers, but I was wondering moreso how easy it would be to hide bad code if you found a way into the remote repository.

Comment: From the horse's mouth: http://lwn.net/Articles/457142/ which links to: http://www.linux.com/news/featured-blogs/171-jonathan-corbet/491001-the-cracking-of-kernelorg

Answer (score 2):

git won't automatically pull from the remote, users need to call `git pull` from the the remote to get new code, which is not 'without anyone noticing the changes.'

Plus, user can check the remote by `git log <remote-name>` and `git show <remote-name>` to see those changes. If they spot a malicious change, they can always revert it.

Comment: Would it be possible for pulled changes to corrupt the change history in such a way that malicious changes wouldn't appear in `git log`? Could the <3-letter government agency> add a back door to a project through their git repository without anyone noticing the changes?